# Parse JSON with Swift JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swifty-json

How to get Value Radio Name With Swift JSON

I wrote like this

```
let response = JSON["topradio"]["Data"]
```

before this i created model for values but am not able to pic values  like radio_name

```
  {
      "topradio": {
        "result": "success",
        "Data": [
          [
            {
              "radio_name": "Kantipur",
              "rimage": "radio/1422960479145155755920731096211441695162.jpeg",
              "status": "1",
              "user_faverate": "false",
              "popular_radio": "0",
              "radio_id": "4"
            }
          ]
[
            {
              "radio_name": "Kantipur",
              "rimage": "radio/1422960479145155755920731096211441695162.jpeg",
              "status": "1",
              "user_faverate": "false",
              "popular_radio": "0",
              "radio_id": "4"
            }
          ]
    ]
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try like `let name = JSON["topradio"]["Data"][0][0]["radio_name"]`

Comment: Hint: `Data` is an array, which itself contains an array. You need to either take the first element of the `Data` array and then the first element of that array, or (most probably) to iterate over the array(s) which may contain several objects.

Comment: @jcaron if suppose i have response like that how to parse

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER   NIrav D gives you right answer for one index  but try this for dynamic `let name = JSON["topradio"]["Data"][0][indexValue]["radio_name"]`

Comment: @MuseerAnsari  get in a for loop every object how can i write let name = JSON["topradio"]["Data"][0][indexValue] this

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER What do mean by for loop can you show us what you have tried.

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER it will give you Radio Name list. when you will run a loop till `JSON["topradio"]["Data"][0].Count `

Comment: @yea all of your suggestions helped me i am able to fixed it and thanks all of you guys

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER Is my answer doesn't works for you?

Comment: @NiravD your answer is also  correct thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your nested `data` Array this way.

```
let dataArray = JSON["topradio"]["Data"].array
for item in dataArray {
    let itemArray = item.array
    for subItem in itemArray {
        if let name = subItem["radio_name"].string {
            print(name)
        }
    }
}
```